# Why is `if` so much faster when checked before a statement than after a statement?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, performance-testing

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
s = """
if x > 10:
    x -= 10
else:
    x = 0
"""
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(s, setup="x=5", number=99999999))
```

Outputs approximately 3 seconds on my computer, regardless of the setup (`x=5` vs `x=15`, no difference)

---

If I were to use much shorter code, one that first decreases `x -= 10` and only then checks if `x < 0`, I will get much worse results:

```
s = """
x -= 10
if x < 0:
    x = 0
"""
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(s, setup="x=5", number=99999999))
```

It outputs around 6 seconds, again regardless whether the initial value of `x` was `5` or `15`.

---

I understand that it would be slower when `x < 10` since we'd first call `x -= 10` and then set `x = 0` instead of simply setting `x` once.

The thing is, 99% of the time the `x`'s initial value in my program is set to a number much higher than 10, so I thought I'd use the shorter version since most of the time I should see no difference in performance.

However, there's a huge difference in performance even when `x > 10`, why's this?

Comment: this timing difference occurs in python 2.7 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your premise is wrong. `setup` only gets run once for the entire `timeit`. If you make sure that `x` stays above `10` then the symptoms disappear:

```
>>> s1 = """
... if x > 10:
...     x -= 10
... else:
...     x = 0
... """
>>> s2 = """
... x -= 10
... if x < 0:
...     x = 0
... """
>>> import timeit
>>> print(timeit.timeit(s1, setup="x=1000000000", number=99999999))
8.934118068675566
>>> print(timeit.timeit(s2, setup="x=1000000000", number=99999999))
8.744505329313448
```

Comment: I've used `timeit.timeit()` a million times before and I'm supposed to be very aware of how the setup parameter works... Funny how our brain can miss something so obvious if it thinks everything **should** work. Thank you for the answer, good catch :)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I actually got bitten by this too when commenting on Will's answer, someone mentioned to me (but that person now deleted his comment, so can't give credit as I don't remember). That mention lead me to this answer.

Answer (score -2):

**Update**: this was mistaken; leaving it up as a record of what *didn't* cause the behavior

It seems at least somewhat likely this is an artifact of the way the code is being run under `timeit.timeit`. You could test for this by timing a single run of code like:

```python
x = 5
for i in xrange(99999999):
  x -= 10
  if x < 0:
    x = 0
```

for the second case, and comparing that timing to a similar rewrite of the first.

Comment: I misunderstood the `setup` parameter, that portion of your answer is at least correct.

Comment: @orlp `xrange` is a built-in in python 2.X.  whether `x = 5` is inside the loop doesn't matter, as this line is the same for both methods.  that the behavior stays after using this answer doesn't mean it's a bad answer; it just means that the difference isn't an artifact of using `timeit`.

Comment: @dbliss But that implies the answer is bad, because that's all the answer says, no? By the way the current downvote isn't mine - I removed mine until further inspection.